# Обновить значения функции Q(1-2) методом q-learning, в соответствии с заданной схемой и параметрами

Tags: нейронные-сети, обучение-с-подкреплением

В процессе изучения методов обучения с подкреплением, наткнулся на схему, в соответствии с которой необходимо обновить значения функции Q для перехода из состояния 1 в состояние 2 (Q(1-2)). Пытался решить задачу самостоятельно, но полученный в ходе решения ответ, система засчитывает, как неверный. Не могли бы Вы подсказать, в чем ошибка моего решения и привести пример корректного решения данного задания?

Исходная схема, условие, а так же параметры задачи, будут приведены в приложенном скриншоте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моя реализация решения данной задачи:

Q_new(1;2) = Q_curr(1;2) + α(r(1) + γ*max[Q(2;3), Q(2;4)] - Q_curr(1;2))

Q_new(1;2) = (α - 1)*Q_curr(1;2) + α(r(1) + γ * max[Q(2;3), Q(2;4)])

Q_new(1;2) = (1 - 1)*Q_curr(1;2) + 1(r(1) + γ * max[Q(2;3), Q(2;4)])

Q_new(1;2) = r(1) + γ*max[Q(2;3), Q(2;4)] = 1 + 0,9 * 1 = 1,9

Понимаю, что такого вида задачи не совсем типичные для stackoverflow, но надеюсь на Ваше понимание и помощь.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

Оказалось, что ошибка в тестах. Решение верное)

Моя реализация решения данной задачи:

```
Q_new(1;2) = Q_curr(1;2) + α(r(1) + γ*max[Q(2;3), Q(2;4)] - Q_curr(1;2))

Q_new(1;2) = (α - 1)*Q_curr(1;2) + α(r(1) + γ * max[Q(2;3), Q(2;4)])

Q_new(1;2) = (1 - 1)*Q_curr(1;2) + 1(r(1) + γ * max[Q(2;3), Q(2;4)])

Q_new(1;2) = r(1) + γ*max[Q(2;3), Q(2;4)] = 1 + 0,9 * 1 = 1,9
```

Ответ: 1,9